# Convert array of ints to array of characters and vice versa in Julia

Tags: python, numpy, julia

In Python/NumPy, I can convert arrays of ints to arrays of characters quite easily. How can I do this in Julia?

For example in Python:

```
In [6]: np.array(["A", "T", "C"]).view(np.int32)
Out[6]: array([65, 84, 67], dtype=int32)
```

And vice versa

```
In [15]: np.array([65, 84, 67]).view("S8")
Out[15]:
array([b'A', b'T', b'C'],
      dtype='|S8')
```

Comment: With numpy 1.10.2, `np.array(["A", "T", "C"]).view(np.int32)` gives `ValueError: new type not compatible with array.`  But `np.array(["A", "T", "C"]).view(np.uint8)` works.

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: Ah, good point.  I used python 2.7.  With python 3, your example works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`reinterpret`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/arrays/#Base.reinterpret):

```
julia> a = ['A' 'T' 'C']
1x3 Array{Char,2}:
 'A'  'T'  'C'

julia> b = reinterpret(Int32, a)
1x3 Array{Int32,2}:
 65  84  67
```

That makes `a` and `b` view the same memory, like a numpy "view".  For example, if I change an element of `a`:

```
julia> a[1] = 'Z'
'Z'
```

`b` is also changed:

```
julia> b
1x3 Array{Int32,2}:
 90  84  67
```

Answer (score 2):

use `Char` and `Int`:

```
Char(120) # = 'x'
Int('x') # = 120
```

A more complete answer:

```
ints = [65, 84, 67]
chars = map(Char, ints)
```

and

```
chars = ['A', 'T', 'C']
ints = map(Int, chars)
```

notice that characters and strings are of different types in Julia, see http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/strings/#characters

EDIT:
You can also use the constructors `Char` and `Int`:

```
Char[65, 84, 67]
Int['A', 'T', 'C']
```

Comment: Is there a faster way than map? The numpy operation is in-place and is basically instantaneous even for very large arrays.

Comment: I guess you can loop over the array, usually loops are fast in Julia. Also you can use the constructors `Char[65, 84, 67]` and `Int['A', 'T', 'C']` for a more in-place approach but I'm not sure if that would be faster.

Comment: @Higany or use `map!` instead.

Answer (score 1):

For a more instantaneous conversion, you can use `ASCIIString`s and `UInt8` arrays. `Char`s take four bytes of memory and don't use the compact one byte representation. The code will be:

```
# chars in s1 to ints in v1
s1 = ASCIIString("ATC")
v1 = s.data

# ints in v2 to chars in s2
v2 = UInt8[65,66,67]
s2 = ASCIIString(v)
```

In both cases, the same memory is backing both variables, meaning the operation is "instantaneous" but changing one variable would change the other.

Comment: Strings are immutable, which may complicate modification (you can always dig into the internal `data` field), but are still useful for manipulation and reading.